# There exist holomorphic maps from a torus $T$ to the sphere $S$ of all degree $\geq 2$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, riemann-surfaces

While reading through "[Restrictions on harmonic maps of surfaces](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938376900422/pdf?md5=79a360fbd50aeae467c673f9289959b9&pid=1-s2.0-0040938376900422-main.pdf)" by J. Eells and J. C. Wood I came across the lines:

> We know that there are holomorphic maps from a torus $T$ to the sphere $S$ of all degrees $\geq 2$. These provide harmonic maps $\phi: (T,g) \to (S,h)$ with degree $\geq 2$, whatever the metrics $g$ and $h$; and are essentially the only ones with those degrees.

I basically have two questions:

1. How would I go about proving that there are holomorphic maps from a torus $T$ to the sphere $S$ of all degrees $\geq 2$.
2. Why are they essentially the only ones with those degrees?

Comment: Do you know any special cases at all of the existence portion of your question?

Comment: Also, do you know the [Riemann-Hurwitz formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann–Hurwitz_formula)?

Comment: No, I don't know any specail cases for the existence portion of the question. Regarding the Riemann-Hurwitz formula, I am familiar with it and was able to show that there does not exist a holomorphic map of degree $1$ from the torus to the sphere but somehow I don't manage to show that there exist holomorphic maps of degree $\geq 2$.

Comment: You need Riemann surface theory — in particular, the Riemann-Roch Theorem. This has nothing to do with Riemannian geometry.

Comment: I agree, I have removed the tag.